# Error "Member get_attribute is unknown" in selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, attributes, webdriver

I'm using selenium in python and simply trying to get an attribute from a HTML element, but the "get_attribute" is not being recognized.

I already imported *webdriver* from *selenium*, and that's what I'm doing:

```
element = driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value='//*[@id="example"]').click()

html_content = element.get_attribute('outerHTML')
```

The error that is occuring is the following:

```
Cannot access member "get_attribute" for type "None"
Member "get_attribute" is unknown
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  This means that it couldn't find the given element, and so ```element``` is ```None```

Comment: @ewokx actually, `WebElement.click()` returns `None`. Also, that reads like a `PyLance` warning, not an actual error message.

Comment: @Axe319 Point taken.

Comment: Now it seems kinda obvious, but I would never imagine the problem was the `click()`. Thank you a lot @Axe319 and @ewokx!